# CartoDB and Mysql Connection

Tags: carto, mysql

I have a MySQL database.I want to connect it with Carto.

When I got the backup-file on mysql database, Carto said unknown file type.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is not connection at the moment. A workaround would be to generate a csv file from your MySQL database and then import it into CARTO.